# Feeble Attempt at using very low level Python for a Simple Script

Tags: python, if-statement

I cannot seem to understand why this piece of code is not running, I am new to Python and programming as a whole. The error it is returning is one of incorrect syntax, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```py
heightDescription = ["short", "average", "tall", "very tall"]

height = 0

if int(height) <= 188:
    print(heightDescription[-1])

if int(height) in range(176, 187)
    print(heightDescription[2])

if int(height) in range(161, 175)
    print(heightDescription[1])

if int(height) in range(1, 174)
    print(heightDescription[0])
```

Comment: Take a careful look at your first `if` and compare it to your others. What is different with it? Take a look at the _line_ referenced by the error message. Does that help?

Comment: you're missing colons after ifs thats your error.

Comment: next time, copy paste your actual error message.  fwiw, you also a) dont need to cast height to int, it's already an int b) are not using range for its intended purpose.  look into if/elif and also if `176 < height < 187`

Comment: @Chris yes the line is the 8th and I am uncertain what the issue is.

Comment: @JLPeyret thanks i guess i'll just keep learning before trying something like this.

Comment: Also, 2 people have answered your question. If the solution works, than please press the checkmark next to the answer, otherwise this question will keep popping up again...

Comment: @phatboydave You probably meant `>=` rather than `<=` in your first `if`.

Comment: no worries.  you've made your first post here and at least 1 person is happy for the rep.   welcome aboard.  but, yeah, look into what's available in Python conditional statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Unisigned Arduino's answer, I fixed your program. Your range's are overlapping, so sometimes you get two descriptions.

So I fixed the range's, and here is the full code:

```py
heightDescription = ["short", "average", "tall", "very tall"]

height = 1000

if int(height) <= 188:
    print(heightDescription[0])

if int(height) in range(188, 198):
    print(heightDescription[1])

if int(height) in range(198, 208):
    print(heightDescription[2])

if int(height) in range(208, 228):
    print(heightDescription[3])
else:
    print(heightDescription[3])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You completely changed all the ranges! I suspect the only issue with the overlapping ranges was that the OP had the first inequality the wrong way round. (The OP's numbers are clearly intended to be human heights in cm, so the values you've chosen are interesting...)

Comment: @alaniwi If you look at the original code, you can see that  first comes 188, then 188 - 198, then 198 - 208, etc. It seems normal to me programmatically :)

Comment: Thank you that did the trick and also taught me that I have much to learn, do you recommend any resources?

Comment: @phatboydave If you want to learn about python if statements then [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2018/01/python-if-statement-example/)

Comment: Thanks again any tips?

Comment: @phatboydave Not really. The only advice I can give you is to learn python slowly. You will understand python over time.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the colons after the `if` statements:

```py
heightDescription = ["short", "average", "tall", "very tall"]

height = 0

if int(height) <= 188: 
    print(heightDescription[-1])

if int(height) in range(176, 187):  # <-- Added colon
    print(heightDescription[2])

if int(height) in range(161, 175):  # <-- Added colon
    print(heightDescription[1])

if int(height) in range(1, 174):  # <-- Added colon
    print(heightDescription[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

ensure all of your `if` conditions have a colon (`:`) at the end

```py
if abcdef:
    #
```

Here are a few [examples](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-if-elif-else-statement) that are very close to what you're attempting.

Comment: This adds nothing new to the current answer.

Comment: @10Rep  there's < 20 sec difference between the 1st answer and this.  so hardly fair to point the "nothing new to current answer" cannon, innit?

Comment: @JLPeyret Oh, I didn't notice that. I guess your answer **does** list a link.

Answer (score 0):

So the syntax error you're getting is from missing colons after the logical statement in the `if` conditional.

Additionally, your logic needs work because you will end up getting multiple printouts for some values.

Here's a more logically sound formulation of your code:

```
heightDescription = ["short", "average", "tall", "very tall"]

height = 0

if int(height) >= 187:
    print(heightDescription[-1])

elif int(height) in range(175, 187):
    print(heightDescription[2])

elif int(height) in range(161, 175):
    print(heightDescription[1])

elif int(height) in range(1, 161):
    print(heightDescription[0])
else: 
    print('no height')
```

Comment: This still leaves the problem that the values 187 and 175 are not covered by any of the conditions (except the `else`), probably because the OP has misunderstood exactly what `range` does and not realised that it stops one short of the upper limit. I objected to 10 Rep totally changing the ranges in his/her answer, but a slight tweak to the ranges in order to correct this issue would be justified.

Comment: Also the `range(1,174)` is probably intended to be `range(1,161)` - although it so happens that your use `elif` will happen to deal with that.

Comment: You're correct. I didn't change the values from the OP, but they would need to be altered to not contain gaps